# How to create a java entity for Elasticsearch aliases?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data, alias, spring-data-elasticsearch

I created an alias using the command:

```
POST /_aliases
{
  "actions": [
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "books",
        "alias": "combined-alias"
      }
    },
    {
      "add": {
        "index": "movies",
        "alias": "combined-alias"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Books index mappings look like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "bookId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "entityId": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "bookId"
        },
        "creationDate": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createAt": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "creationDate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Movies index mappings look like this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "movieId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "entityId": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "movieId"
        },
        "createDate": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "createAt": {
          "type": "alias",
          "path": "createDate"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How could I create Java entity to get list of movies and books in one list?

I was trying to create a Java entity like this:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Document(indexName = "combined-alias", createIndex=false)
public class Product {

    @Id
    private String uuid;

    private String entityId;

    private ZonedDateTime createAt;

}
```

And repository:

```
public interface ProductRepository extends ReactiveElasticsearchRepository<Product, Long> {

    Flux<Product> findAll();
}
```

I expected to get the entityId and createAt when I made the HTTP request, but these fields are always null. If I add the movieId field to the entity, then I successfully receive it in the response. The problem is that I can't get the alias field like entityId.

Comment: In your case, you have created an alias called "combined-alias" that includes both "books" and "movies" indices. However, when you map fields from both indices to a single Java entity called Product, Elasticsearch may not know how to handle fields with the same name but different types or mappings from different indices.
To address this issue, you might consider creating separate Java entities for "books" and "movies" and using different repository interfaces for each.

Comment: @AnisRafid I need to combine both indexes and return them to the ui. I can't separate them. I'm returning an HTTP response which should be a list of products. 
I want to do this in a request to elastic, because there are a lot of movies and books. Yes, and filters need to be implemented in the future, for example, to sort by date